# command line option to display coverage in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, test-coverage, python-coverage

When I use [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) from terminal to display test result with coverage I get error and missing lines that are actually covered

`$ python -m nose.core test_utils.py -s --with-coverage`

saying

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_utils')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 413, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Development/python/slideShow/tests/test_utils.py", line 50, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 128, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 100, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_utils'

Name      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------
PyQt4         0      0   100%   
getopt      103    103     0%   34-210
mox         597    597     0%   17-1898
stubout      50     50     0%   17-142
utils        23     16    30%   8-10, 13-20, 23, 26-30
```

how is the test_utils not found? I am standing in the same directory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright while troubleshooting I got my answer,

the test module have to have

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()`

in order for `python -m nose.core test_utils.TestUtils --with-coverage` to work

earlier i just had `unittest.main()`